# Flatten D3.js Nested Data or Map it to new Dataset

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, charts

Total noob to D3.js and working on creating my first grouped bar chart. However I'm having trouble making my data fit with the examples online. I am trying to use this example here, with my data that has been nested JSON with D3.

My problem is i cant use the d3.keys method to retrieve keys because my keys are not the state names. They are just `Key`.

Not to mention the second half `forEach` wont work because again the keys are not the State names, they are just the term `key`. So `+d[name]` will try `d[MAPLE]` when really my value is inside a key of `d.values[(Get the Value where the key = name)]`.   Just really confused how to do this once the data has been nested in JSON

How would I go about getting all possible Key Values, and then mapping the keys with the next level of keys and values? Using a similar example as below but with my JSON nested data.

```
var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });
```

My data is as so

```
{
    "key": "1/10/2014",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Texas",
        "values": 200
      },
      {
        "key": "Colorado",
        "values": 300
      },
      {
        "key": "Utah",
        "values": 227
      }
    ]
  },{
    "key": "2/10/2014",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Texas",
        "values": 225
      },
      {
        "key": "Colorado",
        "values": 241
      },
      {
        "key": "Utah",
        "values": 500
      }

    ]
  }
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to group by state or date (ie, along the x-axis will it be "Texas", "Colorado"... or "1/10/2014", "2/10/2014")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question if the aim is to group by state ("Texas", "Colorado"...) or date ("1/10/2014", "2/10/2014"...) along the x-axis.

Assuming date (because that's how the data is currently structured), here's a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/C8lkPMGanFY9BkTc6f1i?p=preview

The code that processes the data into a format that your existing D3 code for grouped bar chart can handle looks like this:

```
// Call the first mapping function on every 'date' in the data array
processed_data = data.map( function (d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    var total = 0;
    return {
        date: d.key,
        // Call the second mapping function on every 'state' in the given date array
        values: (d.values).map( function (d) {
            return_object = {
                state: d.key,
                count: d.values,
                y0: y0,
                y1: y0 + d.values
            };
        // Calculate the updated y0 for each new state in a given date
        y0 = y0 + d.values;
        // Add the total for a given state to the sum total for that date
        total = total + d.values;
        return return_object;
        }),
        total: total
    };
});
```

We use nested `array.map` transforms to manipulate your two-level nested data into the expected format and calculate `y0`, `y1` and `total` values. Your `processed_data` object will then look like this:

[image: processed_data view in console]

The only other tricky bit will be to calculate your list of unique states, in order to define the `color.domain`. If you don't want to hard-code this (e.g. because the list may vary from dataset to dataset, you could use this approach:

```
// Define the color domain, by first building a list of states:
var states = [];
// Loop through each date
processed_data.forEach(
    function (d) {
        // Loop through each state in that date
        d.values.forEach(
            function(d) {
                // add to the array if not already present
                if (!(states.indexOf(d.state) > -1)) {
                    states.push(d.state)
                }
            }
        ) 
    }
);
color.domain(states);
```

Comment: Took a while but i was able to hack it together and make it work, just came across your answer and its alot cleaner than what i did. Will implement this now!  Thanks!