# How to prepare data for d3 stacked barchart using rollup

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am new to JavaScript and D3.js and atm trying to create an Angular App with a stacked bar chart visualisation of the number of different test results 'OK', 'NOK' and 'Aborted' of each day as a stacked bar in the y-axis and the dates as the x-axis.

My data.csv looks like this:

```
Date;Result
20-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
20-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
21-05-2021 21:48:45;NOK
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
22-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
```

Since I need to count the results per day I first parse the date into the right format using timeParse and then I use the timeDay.floor method to get rid of the time:

```js
let jsonObj = await d3.dsv(";", "/assets/data.csv", function (d) {

  let time = timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %-H:%M:%S")(d['Date'])
  let date = timeDay.floor(new Date(time));

  return {
    Date: date,
    Result: d.Result
  };
})
```

If I understand correctly, this gives me an array with < date | string > for every test result.

To now summarize the counts of the test results of identical days I use rollup:

```js
let data_count = rollup(jsonObj, v => v.length, d => d.Date, d => d.Result)
```

Now I have a nested Map with the date (only one for each day) as key and the values as the test result each with the summed number for that day.

I foud several examples on how to continue that don't need to use the rollup method e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853693/flatten-d3-js-nested-data-or-map-it-to-new-dataset)
and tried to adapt it to my map:

```js
let processed_data = data_count.map( d => {
  let y0 = 0;
  let total = 0;
  return {
    date: d.key,
    //call second mapping function on every test-result
    values: (d.valules).map( d => {
      let return_object = {
        result: d.key,
        count: d.values,
        y0: y0,
        y1: y0 + d.values
      };
    //calculate the updated y0 for each new test-result on a given date
    y0 = y0 + d.values;
    //add the total for a given test-result to the sum total for that test-result
    total = total + d.values;
    return return_object;  
    }),
    total: total
  };
});
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'InternMap<Date, InternMap<string, number>>'.ts(2339)
```

I understand that the map function can't be used on maps, I guess.
I also tried to rewrite this part into separate functions to not use the map function but it doesn't work either. Maybe I have some syntax error or something but I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
```

I probably need to use the get() method for the values of a map, but not sure how to implement it.

Now I am stuck as to how I should continue to prepare the data for the stacked bar chart. In this example from [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/luxifertran/cafcc1c3505a536594e1) the CSV looks different. I was thinking about somehow manipulating my data to fit that example's shape:

```
Date;OK;NOK;Aborted
20-05-2021 17:54:02;1;0;1
21-05-2021 21:48:45;0;1;0
22-05-2021 17:55:24;2;0;1
```

But I have no idea how to go about it.
Any help as to how to prepare my data would be welcome. Maybe I should not use the rollup method, but I feel like it's a perfect fit for my needs.

Comment: `d3.rollups` will return an array of arrays instead of Map of Maps. Maybe that will be easier to work with?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I tried that too, but had problems later on accessing the right values (dates/results) because of the nesting. The values are not connected to any keys then.

Comment: What is the expected data structure you need to pass to D3 before `enter()` ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky That I unfortunately don't know. It seems all examples I found already have an array similar to the one at the bottom of my qestion. Ideally only with one date for each day and without the time. Then I could follow the [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/luxifertran/cafcc1c3505a536594e1 "http://bl.ocks.org/luxifertran/cafcc1c3505a536594e1") example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we run with the idea that you ultimately want to leverage some existing code examples and therefore need data shaped like this :

```
Date;OK;NOK;Aborted
20-05-2021 17:54:02;1;0;1
21-05-2021 21:48:45;0;1;0
22-05-2021 17:55:24;2;0;1
```

There are several things to consider:

1. You are converting your data from dense to sparse in that you need to create a zero data point for e.g. `NOK` on `20-05-2021` because that data point did not exist in the original data.
2. You need the distinct of the `Result` values as row headers in the transformed data. You can get this with: `const columns = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.Result))];`
3. You found that you can't use `Array.protoype.map` on a `Map` object, so you just need to consider the other options (two presented below) for iterating over `Map` objects e.g. use [`Map.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) or [`Map.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).

To achieve this re-shaped data with `d3.rollup`:

- Wrap the `d3.rollup` statement in `Array.from(...)` which gets you [`Map.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) which you can pass to a `reduce` function.
- In the `reduce` function you can then access the `[key, value]` pairs of the outer `Map` where `value` is itself a `Map` (nested by `d3.rollup`)
- Then iterate `columns` (the distinct of `Result`) in order to assess if you need to either take the value in the inner `Map` (aggregate of that days `Result`) or insert a `0` because that `Result` did not occur on that day (per point (1)).

  In the example, this line:

  `resultColumns.map(col => row[col] = innerMap.has(col) ? innerMap.get(col) : 0);`

  Means: for a column header, if the inner `Map` `has` that column header *as a key*, then `get` the value *per that key*, otherwise it is zero.

Working example:

```js
// your data setup
const csv = `Date;Result
20-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
20-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
21-05-2021 21:48:45;NOK
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
22-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK`;

// your data processing
const data = d3.dsvFormat(";").parse(csv, d => {
  const time = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %-H:%M:%S")(d.Date);
  const date = d3.timeDay.floor(new Date(time));
  return {
    Date: date,
    Result: d.Result
  }
});

// distinct Results for column headers per point (2)
const resultColumns = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.Result))];

// cast nested Maps to array of objects
const data_wide = Array.from( // get the Map.entries()
  d3.rollup(
    data,
    v => v.length,
    d => d.Date,
    d => d.Result
  )
).reduce((accumlator, [dateKey, innerMap]) => {
  // create a 'row' with a Date property
  let row = {Date: dateKey}
  // add further properties to the 'row' based on existence of keys in the inner Map per point (1)
  resultColumns.map(col => row[col] = innerMap.has(col) ? innerMap.get(col) : 0);
  // store and return the accumulated result
  accumlator.push(row);
  return accumlator;
}, []);

console.log(data_wide);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you prefer a more procedural (and maybe more readable) way to get to the same outcome you can avoid `Array.from(...)` and use the `Map`'s [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) method (which is different from [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) to iterate the outer `Map` and then perform a similar operation to assess if data points of zero need to be created:

```js
// your data setup
const csv = `Date;Result
20-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
20-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
21-05-2021 21:48:45;NOK
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK
22-05-2021 17:54:02;Aborted
22-05-2021 17:55:24;OK`;

// your data processing
const data = d3.dsvFormat(";").parse(csv, d => {
  const time = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %-H:%M:%S")(d.Date);
  const date = d3.timeDay.floor(new Date(time));
  return {
    Date: date,
    Result: d.Result
  }
});

// distinct Results for column headers per point (2)
const resultColumns = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.Result))];

// rollup the data
const rolled = d3.rollup(
  data,
  v => v.length,
  d => d.Date,
  d => d.Result
);

// create an output array
const data_wide = [];

// populate the output array
rolled.forEach((innerMap, dateKey) => {
  // create a 'row' with the date property
  const row = {Date: dateKey}
  // add further properties to the 'row' based on existence of keys in the inner Map per point (1)
  resultColumns.map(col => row[col] = innerMap.has(col) ? innerMap.get(col) : 0);
  // store the result
  data_wide.push(row);
});

console.log(data_wide);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know I am supposed to thank you only by marking it as the correct answer, but: THANK YOU! I hope the SO community will forgive me this time;) This part cost me more time than I'd like to admit. I implemented both methods, and although I will stick with the forEach variant, for now, I will definitely look into the reduce-method for future projects!